# Queue using two stacks in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures

I have a working implementation for the classic "Queue using two stacks" data structure in C++ and am wondering what the best software engineering practice would be for handling const correctness.

The peek() function returns the value at the front of the queue, which may mean that we need to pop everything from one stack and copy it to the other.  One way to use the copy function is to cast the constness away for this as shewn below.  Is there a better way?

```
class MyQueue {
        stack <int> s1;
        stack <int> s2;
public:
    MyQueue() {

    }
    
    void push(int x) {
        s1.push(x);
    }
    
    void copy()
    {
        while (!s1.empty()) {
            s2.push(s1.top());
            s1.pop();
        }
    }
    
    int pop() {
        int res;
        if (s2.empty()) copy();
        if (! s2.empty()) {
            res = s2.top();
            s2.pop();
        }
        return res;
    }
    
    int peek() const {
        if (s2.empty()) ((MyQueue*) (this))->copy();
        return s2.top();        
    }
    
    bool empty() const {
        return s1.empty() && s2.empty();
    }
};
```

Comment: Before getting into a const correctness, why do you do a `copy` in `pop`? Also, `copy` shouldn't be a public method, I think.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to adjust the design a bit, so that `s2` is never empty unless the queue is empty.  Then the difficult question goes away, and the code gets simpler, too:

```
class MyQueue {
    stack <int> s1;
    stack <int> s2;
public:
    MyQueue() {
    }
    
    void push(int x) {
        if (s2.empty()) {
            // queue is empty
            s2.push(x);
        } else {
            s1.push(x);
        }
    }
    
    int pop() {
        int res = s2.pop();
        if (s2.empty())
            copy();
        return res;
    }
    
    int peek() const {
        return s2.top();        
    }
    
    bool empty() const {
        return s2.empty();
    }

private:
    void copy()
    {
        while (!s1.empty()) {
            s2.push(s1.pop());
        }
    }    
};
```